# Arrays and objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, oop

If arrays are objects in Java then why they are not initialized using syntax `X x = new X();`?

Like if there is a class named `Person`, and I have to create an object of that class then I  will use syntax: `Person p1 = new Person();`. So why we don't declare arrays in the same way?

Please explain, arrays should be initialize using that syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Comment: You seem to be under impression that objects in Java are only class instances. That is not true. There are **two** kinds of objects in Java: (1) class instances, and (2) arrays - which are separate from class instances, so they can follow different syntax. The `new ClassName(arguments)` syntax is for creating instance of `ClassName`. For arrays we can use for instance `new TypeName[size]`, but there are also other ways like `String strArray = {"abc", "def"};`.

Comment: Because that's how the language is designed. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585), and [edit] your question to clarify what kind of answer you are looking for here.

Comment: Arrays are historically pointers, not objects. In a purely functional language, you can have arrays and no objects. Arrays transcend OOP.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can. While it is allowed to omit `new String[]` in array declaration, the full syntax is

```
String[] arr = new String[] { "Hello", "World" };
```

which is a longer way to write

```
String[] arr = { "Hello", "World" }; // This is only valid at declaration time.
```

both are just a shorter way to write

```
String[] arr = new String[2];
arr[0] = "Hello";
arr[1] = "World";
```

Comment: Note that you cannot do the following, `String[] arr; arr = { "Hello", "World" };`, or else you will get an _"Array constants can only be used in initializers"_ error. The short-hand syntax  can only be used in a constant declaration.